# Is it possible to bind a javascript function so that its local context is same as 'this'?

Tags: javascript, function, functional-programming

Here's a function `nameExists` that can be bound to an object and return whether its name attribute is not empty.

```
var nameExists = function(){
  return this.name.length > 0;
}
var person = {name: "John"};
var johnHasName = nameExists.bind(person);
johnHasName();
```

Now, I want to be able to somehow simplify this `nameExists` function so that I don't need to use `this` keyword anymore, which would then look like this:

```
var nameExists = function(){
  return name.length > 0;
}
```

This assumes that the function's local context is equal to its `this` context. Basically I'm looking for a way to call/bind/apply this function in any way possible so that I don't have to use `this` keyword.

I have good reasons for trying to do this so please don't judge. I am not even sure if this is possible and have been thinking for a bit but couldn't come up with an idea. I would appreciate help!

p.s.
The reason I'm trying to do this is because I am trying to dynamically construct a filter function from string. So for example if I wanted to create a filter function that determines if a person has a name and age is over 20, I would write something like this:

```
var john = {name: "john", age: 3};
var filter = "this.name.length > 0 && this.age > 20";
var fun = new Function("return " + filter);
var filterForJohn = fun.bind(john);
filterForJohn();
```

It works fine that way, but I just don't like the verbosity so would like to simplify the filter string so that I can just write

```
var filter = "name.length > 0 && age > 20";
```

I found it challenging because I know neither the attributes nor their combination of conditions until I have the filter string.

Comment: Why not `nameExists = function(name) {...`? What you are asking for is weird, seems like an XY problem...

Comment: If you have good reasons, please include them in the question. Otherwise that claim is vacuous.

Comment: @elclanrs I just made an edit explaining why I am trying to do this...

Comment: @DanD. Just added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `with` statement to extend the scope chain:

```
var nameExists = function() {
  with(this) {
    // Here you don't need `this`:
    return name.length > 0;
  }
}
```

However, it's slow and its usage is not recommended in non-strict mode and it's forbidden in strict mode.

On web browsers, a crazy alternative would be using event handler content attributes. You can't directly access the value returned by an event handler, but if it's `false` the event will be canceled.

```
var makeObj, callFunc;
(function() {
  var parent = document.createElement('div'),
      eventCanceled;
  parent.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    eventCanceled = e.defaultPrevented;
  });
  makeObj = function(props, funcStr) {
    var obj = document.createElement('div');
    Object.assign(obj, props);
    obj.setAttribute("onclick", "return " + funcStr);
    parent.appendChild(obj);
    return obj;
  };
  callFunc = function(obj) {
    obj.click();
    return !eventCanceled;
  };
})();
var obj = makeObj({name: "john", age: 3}, "name.length > 0 && age > 20");
callFunc(obj); // false
```

Comment: WOW Thank you, I've been programming in JS for quite a while but have never heard of it until now, just checked and this definitely does solve my problem. I think I will go with the `with` syntax since i'm trying to use this in node.js (also I like the simplicity). By the way could you elaborate on slowness? Is it that serious? And why?

Comment: See [`with` - Performance pro & contra](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with#Performance_pro_contra) on MDN: "*all identifiers that aren't members of the specified object will be found more slowly in a 'with' block*"

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I am guessing it wouldn't affect performance at least in this particular case where I will never have a local variable but only access attributes within `this` context, right? (Sorry for keep asking, just wanted to confirm)

Comment: @Vlad From that article, it seems so. But that's implementation-dependent, and I don't know what implementations do.